# How can I use a hardware wallet with a pool

Tags: mining-pools, hardware-wallet

This might be a totally dumb question but I am trying to understand bitcoin mining, I hope I am bearable.

I am trying to figure out if I can use a hardware wallet with a mining pool. I have an account on slushpool.com but I don't yet have a mining device yet.

In my current understanding (which might be totally useless), I have to install a software (that works with slushpool) on a computer and configure it, connect the mining device to the computer and have some kind of a wallet for payout. The pool with give me a payout every time I reach a threshhold.

How can I use a hardware wallet with this setup? Is there something different that I need to know? My goal is to come up with a setup with as little dependency on external entities that need a "cut" from what I make.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,
Paras

Comment: You can add the hardware wallet public address for BTC into Slushpool. It sends the funds to you device. It will be picked up the next time you sync your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardware wallet will have a public address that you use to send coins to. Each coin will have a specific public address. BTC will have it's own. It is the address generated when you open the BTC wallet on your hardware device and elect to 'receive'. Copy and add that into the mining program.

Comment: I know this is a bit late but I just wanted to give you an update. I downloaded a wallet and bought a raspberry pi and a gekko science asic miner. It worked fine but the payout period was about 2 years. So I quit bitcoin mining and switched to emarks. It is not worth as much as a bitcoin but it atleast gives me a payout. I don't care about making a profit